# Javascript timezones and clocks

Tags: javascript

I need to implement 3 clocks on one page. Simple text clocks. These need to display the current time in London, New York and Sydney.

I know I shouldn't just use offset times as they do not account for daylight saving and also that I am pretty sure the javascript time provided will be the local time on the system of the user. I.e if I just set London to be the current time and New York to be minus 5 hours. That would work for all London based computer users but not for any other timezones.

Am I correct in that logic? Is there any suggested solution? I can't be the first trying to get a concrete time out of javascript no matter on location.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to where you are stuck?  There are large libraries built around time conversion, if that's what you are seeking.  Native JavaScript doesn't have a lot of functionality as far as date/time goes.

Comment: Set the UTC date then set the timezone.

Comment: A quick search for "javascript world clock" gives this really great resource: http://www.proglogic.com/code/javascript/time/worldclock.php

Comment: http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 0):

The server is much more capable of handling dates and times in other timezones than JavaScript is, especially since JavaScript takes the time from the user's machine, whatever it may be.

So my solution would be:

1. On page load, have the server tell the browser what time it is right now in those desired timezones.
2. Every so often - for example, every time a half-hour lands - query the server for updated times to make sure the browser is still in sync.

Done! :)